# When does a solution to $a^x\equiv b\pmod m$ exist, and how is the smallest solution denoted?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, notation, terminology, modular-arithmetic

Given fixed integers $a,b,m$ such that $\gcd(a,m)=1$, how do I know if there exists an integer $x$ such that $a^x\equiv b\text{ mod } m$, also if a solution does exist, what is the typical notation for denoting the smallest positive solution $x$ to that modular equation, and are there any inequalities known for the value of x if it exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deciding whether a solution exists is, in general, difficult. Finding a solution, if one does exist, is, in general, difficult. No useful inequalities are possible. The problem goes by the name of "discrete logarithm," and a search for that term should bring you much enlightenment.

Comment: What about the special case $b=1$, and we drop the assumption gcd(a,m) are coprime, (if they are $\phi(m)=x$ is a solution)

Comment: @Ethan If $b=1$ and $\gcd(a,m) \neq 1$, then $x=0$.

Comment: I meant to say postive solutions sorry, $x=0$  isn't really useful

Comment: @Ethan: if $\gcd(a,m)\ne1$, then as Marvis says $x=0$ is the only solution. If $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then $x\equiv0\pmod{\varphi(m)}$ is a solution by [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem), where $\varphi$ is the [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: Why is it the only solution?

Comment: @Ethan: because $\gcd(a,m)$ divides $a^x$ for all $x\gt0$.  Thus $a^x\not\equiv1\pmod{m}$.

Comment: If $a^x\equiv 1\text{ mod m}$ then $a^x-mk=1$ (for some integer k), therefore gcd(a,m) divides 1, therefore gcd(a,m)=1? is that logic ok?

Comment: @Ethan: yes, that is the [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_%28logic%29) of what Marvis and I are saying. Also, if you want us to see that you have replied to us, it is best to use `@username` so that we get notified.